# How to get started on searching through bean properties with Apache Lucene?

Tags: java, apache, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm trying out full text search engine frameworks for a Java EE framework with JPA and don't want to switch to Hibernate which offers the quite neat Hibernate Search feature, so I'm starting with Apache Lucene, now.

I'd like to search through String fields of JPA entities (after creating an index for them, i.e. writer/reader example). I'll use an EJB wrapping the persistence layer to keep the index up-to-date. I assume it's irrelevant that I'm using JPA and Java EE.

Since Apache projects don't have a policy to keep their documentation up-to-date at all or at least mark them outdated most of the examples at https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/TheBasics and similar sites don't work with because classes have and methods have been removed. The same goes for blog posts found via search engine. It's possible to find them, but anything one finds needs to be tried out because there's ca. 90% change that one figures out that the example refers to classes or methods which no longer exist...

I'm looking for any example showing the above use case with an up-to-date version of Lucene which is 6.5.0 afaik.

Comment: So you are looking for index creation as well as searcher code for that version? I guess, JPA part in your question is irrelevant for the problem that you face, am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what all has changed in 6.5 but below are codes for Lucene 6.0.0 and compile / run with 6.5.0 too.

**IndexCreation**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

public class IndexCreator {

    public static IndexWriter getWriter() throws IOException{
          File indexDir = new File("D:\\Experiment");
          SimpleAnalyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();
          IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
          indexWriterConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
          IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(indexDir
                .toPath()), indexWriterConfig);
          indexWriter.commit();
          return indexWriter;

    }
}
```

Now you can use this writer to Index your documents using `writer.updateDocument(...)` `writer.addDocument(...)` methods.

Fields can be added to document like below,

```
doc.add(new Field("NAME", "Tom", new FieldType(TextField.TYPE_STORED)));
```

**Searching**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.search.WildcardQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;



public class LuceneSearcher {

    public static void searchIndex() throws IOException{

        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("D:\\Experiment")));

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(new WildcardQuery(new Term("NAME", "*")), 20);

        if (null == hits.scoreDocs || hits.scoreDocs.length <= 0) {
            System.out.println("No Hits1 Found");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(hits.scoreDocs.length + " hits1 Docs found !!");

        for (ScoreDoc hit : hits.scoreDocs) {
            Document doc = searcher.doc(hit.doc);
        }

        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Searcher code assumes that you have an indexed document with `NAME` as field name.

I think, this should be enough to get you started.

Let me know if you need anything else.

I have these maven dependencies,

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: In order to work with Java Beans one needs to use Solr as Lucene doesn't seem to have direct support for it, but Solr is pretty straightforward for this task.

Comment: Lucene is a Java API & SOLR is a ready made tool so its a choice as per one's need. In Lucene, you need to code your own query builder using Java bean properties.